how can I recover (or understand the h5debug output of) my hdf5 file?
I have a hdf5 file that is so large I have to use my home fileserver to write the data (4.04TB, according to macOS's Finder). It is a collection of logits that takes several hours to calculate, and for some reason, after calculating the last chunk of data, it failed in a bad way.
I now see:
h5debug /Volumes/MacBackup-1/gguf/baseline_logits.hdf5

Reading signature at address 0 (rel)
File Super Block...
File name (as opened):                             /Volumes/MacBackup-1/gguf/baseline_logits.hdf5
File name (after resolving symlinks):              /Volumes/MacBackup-1/gguf/baseline_logits.hdf5
File access flags                                  0x00000000
File open reference count:                         1
Address of super block:                            0 (abs)
Size of userblock:                                 0 bytes
Superblock version number:                         0
Free list version number:                          0
Root group symbol table entry version number:      0
Shared header version number:                      0
Size of file offsets (haddr_t type):               8 bytes
Size of file lengths (hsize_t type):               8 bytes
Symbol table leaf node 1/2 rank:                   4
Symbol table internal node 1/2 rank:               16
Indexed storage internal node 1/2 rank:            32
File status flags:                                 0x00
Superblock extension address:                      18446744073709551615 (rel)
Shared object header message table address:        18446744073709551615 (rel)
Shared object header message version number:       0
Number of shared object header message indexes:    0
Address of driver information block:               18446744073709551615 (rel)
Root group symbol table entry:
   Name offset into private heap:                  0
   Object header address:                          96
   Cache info type:                                Symbol Table
   Cached entry information:
      B-tree address:                              136
      Heap address:                                680
Error in closing file!
HDF5: infinite loop closing library
      L,T_top,F,P,P,Z,FD,VL,VL,PL,E,SL,FL,FL,FL,FL,FL,FL,FL,FL,FL,FL,FL,FL,FL,FL,FL,FL,FL,FL,FL,FL,FL,FL,FL,FL,FL,FL,FL,FL,FL,FL,FL,FL,FL,FL,FL,FL,FL,FL,FL,FL,FL,FL,FL,FL,FL,FL,FL,FL,FL,FL,FL,FL,FL,FL,FL,FL,FL,FL,FL,FL,FL,FL,FL,FL,FL,FL,FL,FL,FL,FL,FL,FL,FL,FL,FL,FL,FL,FL,FL,FL,FL,FL,FL,FL,FL,FL,FL,FL,FL,FL,FL,FL

I am not clear what is actually wrong with it from that debug output. In terms of real size, I think it is less than 4TB:
ls -la  /Volumes/MacBackup-1/gguf/baseline_logits.hdf5
-rwx------@ 1 macdev  staff   3.7T Nov 12 12:21 /Volumes/MacBackup-1/gguf/baseline_logits.hdf5

Here's my script's log when it failed, it was not a very specific error message:
[471] 114207.41 ms [472] 24712.48 ms [473] 120010.91 ms [474] 134073.39 ms
INFO - Processed 4 chunks
INFO - Final file size: 3832472.77 MB
Running from 475 to 478
INFO - generate_logits starting (version 0.5.3)
INFO - Loaded precomputed tokens from /Users/Shared/Public/huggingface/salamandra-2b-instruct/imatrix/oscar/calibration-dataset.txt.tokens.npy
INFO - Processing chunks from 475 to 478
INFO - Estimated runtime: 6.11 minutes for 3 remaining chunks
[475] 122266.14 ms [476] 27550.59 ms ERROR - Unexpected error occurred: Can't decrement id ref count (unable to close file, errno = 9, error message = 'Bad file descriptor')
Error occurred. Exiting.

That was as the file was just exceeding 4TB (depending on how you look at it), which seems suspicious, but it is writing (from a Mac) to a windows 11 machine with a 16Tb disk with 13Tb free before this started, formatted in NTFS. My SMB info says I am connected with smb_3.1.1, with LARGE_FILE_SUPPORTED          TRUE, which I would hope would give me the 16Tb available to NTFS.
How can I recover (or understand the h5debug output of) my hdf5 file?

I cannot help with debugging, but to my understanding HDF5 is considered somewhat fragile format, especially in more complex structures and larger files, problems happen. Because of its complex internals, recovery is often very difficult.
With your setup, is it possible to: 1) split the file to smaller parts and have checkpoints in the main program, 2) use some other, more bulletproof file format (parquet, ZARR, etc)?

I was able to simply repack it, because I have the space. Im still unclear if I needed to fully repack it: it seems like rewriting 4TB of data is wasteful when all that is wrong is the metadata
